# Looping through lines of a file and performing a function through each iteration in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I have a file in HDFS called file1 with following lines: (Each line is a directory path)

```
this/is/path1
this/is/path2
this/is/path3
.
.
.
this/is/path1000ormore
```

I have a Scala Spark function as follows:

```
val resultset=sc.hadoopFile(inputpath,classOf[TextInputFormat],classOf[LongWritable],classOf[Text]).flatMap {
case (k, v) => if (k.get == 0) Seq(v.toString) else Seq.empty[String]
}
```

I want to pass each line from "file1" in place of "inputpath" (needs to be a String) in the hadoopFile function, and get the result for each iteration/loop. 
How can I do this?

**Extra info:**

**What the  function actually does:** The function above takes the first file from the directory path specified in place of "inputpath" and gives the first line from the file. I want to do this to all the directory paths that I have stored in "file1", hence I am looking for solutions on how to do it in a loop/iteration.

**Update:**
I tried putting it in a loop like this:

```
val lines=Source.fromFile("/path/to/file1.txt").getLines.toList
for(i<-lines){
val firstLines=sc.hadoopFile(i,classOf[TextInputFormat],classOf[LongWritable],classOf[Text]).flatMap {
case (k, v) => if (k.get == 0) Seq(v.toString) else Seq.empty[String]
}
```

This ran for around 10 min (file1 contains roughly 34,000 lines)  and went through without resulting in any errors. But when I tried to see a few lines of the output with the following command,

```
firstLines.take(3)
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
error: not found: value firstLines
          firstLines
          ^
```

So I don't think the loop ran successfully and thus firstLines never got created, although I have no idea what the problem could be. Can someone provide a solution?

Comment: you can use `sc.wholeTextFile("dir/path")`.

Comment: @mrsrinivas Thats what I did as my next step but I don't know how to successfully pass each line of this text file to my function in a loop manner. The function accepts only String values as its "inputpath" parameter and passing the whole file as one String will not work as it needs to be a valid path. Each line of the file is a valid path, but the whole file as a String is not.

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved in two steps:

1. Read "file1" as usual text file from HDFS, get all elements;
2. For each item from 1), apply "resultset" logic.

Also 2) can be improved: all items from 1) can be joined by comma in one string, string passed as "inputpath" parameter. You will have one RDD with data from all files. Filter "k.get == 0" can be applied for get final result.

First can be implemented in this way:

```
val lines = Source.fromFile("file1.txt").getLines.toSeq.view

val resultDF = lines.map(current =>
  sc.hadoopFile(current, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text]).filter(_._1 == 0)
).reduce(_ union _)

resultDF.take(3).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, please refer to the update I made to my question. I followed your approach and tried putting it in a for loop but it is not successful.